# Trying to implement a Module using namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, module

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to implement a Module using namespaces.

In my `lib/` folder I have the `authorization.rb` file with in this:

```
module Authorizations
  def Authorizations.message
    return "flash_message"
  end
end
```

In my controller I have:

```
class Users::AccountsController < ApplicationController # 'Users' is the namespace
  include Authorizations

  def create
    ...
    flash.now[:notice] =  Authorizations.message
  end
end
```

When I run the `create` method I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method 'message' for Authorizations:Module)
```

**What is wrong?**

---

In the module statement I also tryed these

```
def Authorizations::message
 ...

# or 

def message
  ...
```

and also those don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `RAILS_ROOT/config/application.rb`. Just load the `lib/` folder in this way:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
module Authorizations
  def message
    return "flash_message"
  end
end
```

And then

```
Authorizations::message
```

or if included in the class, just

```
... = message
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Anyway can you be more clear? Maybe it is because for that...